# Is there a way of passing props from child to parent without onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen examples that show how to pass props from a child to its parent with a onClick on onChange event on the child component, but am struggling to figure out how to pass props up passively.

What i'd like is to have the child component that performs a fetch operation and then passes the response up to the parent.

```
// PARENT component
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            homeLink: 'inital'
        }
    }

    handleNamechange(newName) {
        this.setState({
            homeLink: newName
        })
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <section>
                <h1>{this.state.homeLink}</h1>

                <GetUserComponent 
                    changeLink={this.handleNamechange.bind(this)}
                />

            </section>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

And the part I struggle with is sending the props up to the parent WITHOUT the onClick, and just pass the props once the fetch is complete

```
// CHILD Component
class GetUserComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            homeLink: 'xxxx'
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://someapi/getusername', {

        })
        .then(function(response) { 
            return response.json() 
        })
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState(
                { username: data }
            )
        })
    }

    onChangeLink() {
        this.props.changeLink(this.state.homeLink)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span onClick={this.onChangeLink.bind(this)}
                    >Change Header Link</span>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default GetUserComponent;
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong, or whether this simply can't be done and you HAVE to use the click event, but either way would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the parents function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://someapi/getusername', {

    })
    .then(function(response) { 
        return response.json() 
    })
    .then((data) => {
        this.props.changeLink(data);

    })
}
```

It will then execute the `handleNamechange` function and update the parents state.

Comment: No problem, I still remember how confused I was when I tried to figure that out :-D

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think the parent must do the fetch, and give as props the result to the children.

If you really need the child fetch the data, you have to call the callback changeLink given as a props from the parent to the child as it :

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://someapi/getusername', {

    })
    .then(function(response) { 
        return response.json() 
    })
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState(
            { username: data }
        )
        this.props.changeLink(data)
    })
}
```